# Collective Term for (FPGA, GPU, CPU, DSP, NPU)

Tags: terminology

I am looking for a collective term for these compute blocks (FPGA, GPU, CPU, DSP,NPU). I found it in some journal but I cant recall. I want to use it in an article I am writing.

P.S I made up to term "compute blocks" to refer to them but there is indeed a generic term for them

Comment: "compute hardware"?

Comment: sure but there is an engineering term for it which I am looking for

Comment: Fundamentally, the thing you care about in each of those are the ALUs. Otherwise, you might refer to them broadly as "digital logic".

Comment: Processing/Computing engine/core?

Comment: ASIC is generic enough to cover all of them. You just have to consider a general purpose CPU as one of many different specific applications to which an IC is applied.

Comment: @jonk yes i believe ASIC can be generic enough if we remove FPGA from the mentioned set.

Comment: @GENIVI-LEARNER Why wouldn't an FPGA just be yet another "specific application to which an IC is applied?" How you purpose it is just a detail. The general concept of providing such a device is, itself, a specific application area. They are of a kind of thing. I'd say they fit fine. By your thinking, a CPU would need to also be excluded because it can be programmed. And by the way, I worked in FABs (wafer temp measurement.) I've asked those who do this all day every day if they felt that CPUs and FPGAs are, in fact, just another kind of ASIC. They just nodded yes. No argument at all.

Comment: @jonk, The reason for that is the very meaning of the word "Application Specific" in Application Specific Integrated Circuit. FPGA are kinda versatile and can be configured to be CPU (microblaze) or GPU or DSP so for thats why I thought it is excluded from the definition.

Comment: Well, I'll let you call it, then. But if I design a new FPGA that I want to sell and I hire a FAB to make a few wafers for me through a broker, then the process for doing all that is exactly the same and requires all the same tools and skills as any other ASIC. There is no discernable difference. Same with a CPU. Also, used appropriately in conversation, it has never confused anyone within the industry making ICs. But it remains your call. Have at it.

Comment: Yes the manufacturing process is similar as they are array of transistors, resistors, capacitors at atomic level.

Comment: @GENIVI-LEARNER From the perspective of IC manufacturing, it's just a matter of how many masks are required (in my experience often generated by photo-lithography using electron beams emitted via a Wehnelt system), the number of process steps required and what those steps entail. One thing is like another, at this level. If someone generates a custom set of masks and processing steps for an FPGA they want on a single wafer, the only real difference between that single custom wafer and a similarly processed mass-produced FPGA performed in the service of some FPGA giant like Xilinx is *volume*.

Comment: @GENIVI-LEARNER Same thing applies across the board. If a wafer is populated with tens of thousands of tiny custom logic dice that are processed using the same number of processing steps and types and in the same order as, say, some ARM processor -- then there is *no discernible difference* between them, except perhaps yield, volume, required testing before packaging, required testing after packaging but before shipping, and perhaps profits. It's all of a kind and in fact can probably be mixed together in the same run.

Comment: @jonk, I am not sure what you meant by "no discernible difference between them", also I am not sure what you are implying with the mentioned comments. Are you implying if the manufacturing process is similar with similar lithograph, then the underlying IC's are same?

Comment: @GENIVI From about 1989 through about 2006 I worked at various FABs and FAB equipment manufacturers' sites. Everything from an upstart G^2 (now owned by Applied Materials) to Applied and to Intel. G^2 made (makes) RTP furnaces (look like kilns, in the early 1990's) for one-off wafer fabrication on short schedules. Applied makes a lot of stuff for mass manufacturing. Intel, well you know what they do. I have my experiences. That's all. And yes, you can and will often process very different kinds of wafers in the same boats over the same steps. It's what brokers can sell you, in fact.

Comment: @GENIVI But I don't want this to be about you and me, debating. Maybe someone else should *chip* in and say what they want to. (Pun intended.) I'm over it, to be honest. I have a perspective. It's just one perspective of one person who does NOT have a comprehensive god-like view of the world. Others, many others in fact, have vastly more experience and more detailed knowledge than I do. And I would bow to their opinion on this in one second flat. I'm just offering you a thought to consider. That's all. I've no interest in pressing the point if it doesn't work for you.

Comment: @jonk, noted. I do acknowledge what you mean. Its good to hear different perspective. My perspective lies on the 'intent' of the device which differentiates it from others. Take for example a simple transistor, if you merely flip it from its current configuration, you will get completely different circuit characteristic. In CPU based devices, you have a bottleneck of processing the instructions "Opcodes" through the cpu cycle to realize some logic, on the other hand in FPGA, both can do same jobs, but each has certain circuitry which differentiates them.

Comment: @GENIVI If you are bent on "intent" then we are forever separated on this issue. The same thing applies, for example, with the word "embedded" when applied to programming. Some people, whom I vehemently disagree with, think that it is the "intent" that determines whether or not the programming earns the word "embedded." I totally disagree. Absolutely disagree. The *use* of a device has NOTHING important to say about it. What makes embedded programming "embedded" is the much wider skillsets and tool knowledge required to do the job. Not the end-use. The end-use is irrelevant.

Comment: @jonk, I totally agree on the "embedded" programing part, the the wider skillsets pertains to knowledge of utilizing minimalistic logic that is optimized for minimalistic hardware such as arduino.

Comment: @GENIVI It's important to programmers and to those who hire them, to know the difference between embedded programming and Linux or Windows programming. The fact that someone might use a Linux box to run a washing machine does NOT make that an embedded programming job. Only the differentiating knowledge and skill sets as applied to the situation determine that. If the programmers can just use standard libraries and know nothing at all about linkers, memory, hardware, etc, beyond the library docs then it's not embedded programming.

Comment: @GENIVI The same applies to IC wafer manufacturing here. The end use does NOT get to determine what a thing ***is***. I might use a screwdriver to open a jar lid. It's still a screwdriver.

Comment: @jonk I see your point now.

Comment: @GENIVI Thanks. It's still a screwdriver because of what goes on to design one and to make one. It's the people who ***create*** that care about the terms applied. Not the people who ***consume*** an item. Often, consumers have no appreciation whatsoever for what it takes to make something. They will buy toilet paper and have NO CLUES at all about how much design effort has gone into it, so that it doesn't unnecessarily clog up sewer systems and can be processed in plants that handle the sewage, etc.